# Coded UI Mouse.Click() sometimes gets an error about int32

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

When I am trying to preform a mouse.Click() on a certain point inside a viewer I get the following error.

The code first:

```
public void ClickOnViewerSpace(int addX = 0, int addY = 0) {            
        //Mouse.Click(new Point(2439 + addX, 560 + addY));
        int x = _contentContainer.BoundingRectangle.Location.X;
        int y = _contentContainer.BoundingRectangle.Location.Y;
        Mouse.Click(new Point(x + addX, y + addY));
}
```

The error:

> Test Name:    TC1_9_2_AdminEnter Test FullName:    Test Source:    line 427
>   Test Outcome: Failed Test Duration:   0:00:31.5364285
>
> Result Message:    Test method threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException:
>   Cannot perform 'Click' on the control. Additional Details: The control
>   details were not specified. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component. Result StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.MouseButtonClick(Int32
>   x, Int32 y, Int32 nButton, Int32 fEnsureVisible, String
>   bstrKeyModifiers)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.MouseButtonClick(Int32
>   x, Int32 y, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Int32
>   ensureVisible)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestActionExecutorCore.Click(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate)  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException
>   innerException, IPlaybackContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException
>   exception, IPlaybackContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException
>   exception, String actionName, UITestControl uiControl)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestActionExecutorCore.Click(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__5()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(Point
>   screenCoordinate)    at
>   ObjectsRepository.TouchViewer.ClickOnViewerSpace(Int32 addX, Int32
>   addY) in d:\test\auto\ObjectsRepository\TouchViewer.cs:line 109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that even though the `Mouse.Click(Point)` method exists, the CUIT framework does not allow a click action without a `UITestControl`. Here is a good link to follow: [Mouse.Click using Point only](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f86965d4-7dd3-4455-a34c-9c3972869078/mouseclick-using-xy-coordinates?forum=vstest)

The stack trace looks like it aligns with this since every method after the initial `Mouse.Click(Point)` call depends on a `UITestControl`.

Based on the code posted, I would try something like this:

```
public void ClickOnViewerSpace(int addX = 0, int addY = 0)
{
    //int x = _contentContainer.BoundingRectangle.Location.X;
    //int y = _contentContainer.BoundingRectangle.Location.Y;
    //Mouse.Click(new Point(x + addX, y + addY));
    Mouse.Click(_contentContainer, new Point(addX, addY)); // relative coords
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add `_contentContainer.Find()` before generating coordinates based on this control.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the lead on fixing the similar issue which i faced & struck out for two days ... My Search was How to Click on cell with hidden properties of a Grid in Windows application through CodedUI Automation

My Sol goes as below ,.. credits @ [MSDN link dude](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffbaf1e2-aa30-4f78-ac92-dab83c6451f9/cannot-perform-click-on-the-hidden-control?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffbaf1e2-aa30-4f78-ac92-dab83c6451f9/cannot-perform-click-on-the-hidden-control?forum=vsautotest)

public void InstantiateControls()
        {

```
        #region  UserSearch
        frSearchUsers = new ControlWithContainer<WinGroup>(this.SourceControl, By.ControlName("frSearchUsers"));
        txtFindUser = new ControlWithContainer<WinEdit>(this.SourceControl, By.ControlName("txtFindUser"));
        vgrdUsers = new ControlWithContainer<WinWindow>(frSearchUsers.Control.SourceControl, By.ControlName("vgrdUsers"));
        vgrdUserscUSTOM = new ControlWithContainer<WinCustom>(vgrdUsers.Control.SourceControl, By.ControlName("vgrdUsers"));

        #endregion
    }

    public void clickCell()
    {
        var cellGrid = vgrdUserscUSTOM.Control.SourceControl;
        UITestControl cellGridCell = new UITestControl(cellGrid);
        cellGridCell.SearchProperties["ControlType"] = "Cell";
        cellGridCell.SearchProperties["InnerText"] = "Dawson,Jade";            
        if (cellGridCell.TryFind())
        {
            cellGridCell.SetFocus();
            cellGridCell.Find();             

            UITestControlCollection uic = cellGridCell.FindMatchingControls();

            foreach (UITestControl ui in uic)
            {
                if (ui.BoundingRectangle.Width > 0)
                {
                    Mouse.Click(ui);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
```